# What if the gc were optional in go?

Tags: garbage-collection, go

**Would such a language be feasible or are there specific features in go that absolutely require some form of a gc?**

note: I am not anti-gc, but coming from a C/C++ background and working on a real-time server application, I prefer to maintain some level of control how and when memory is reaped (can't have a 10s garbage-collection happening in the middle of a live run).

Are my concerns realistic, given my requirements? Or is the go gc so good that my concerns are unfounded?

Go's gc is my only reservation about attempting a port of my C++ real-time server to go.

Comment: You'd probably be better off asking a separate question specifically about how to measure the runtime impact of GC in go.

Comment: Don't know about go, but a ten second (!) garbage collection sounds very unlikely with modern techniques. A few milliseconds is more likely, and operating systems very often cause delays that long by running virus scanners, waking up dormant processes and swapping virtual memory here and there.

Comment: I have not tried Go but your requirements are very vague. You are much better off to measure it by yourself. Depending on the scenario the GC algorithms might get in your way or not. By asking the question in such a generic way will not give you a useful answer. How much interruption time can you tolerate? Even Windows is not a realtime OS. Are you talking about true realtime or something else?

Comment: thank you for your comments, Dan (+1) - I will take up your suggestion and post a better question later today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go with optional GC would require language changes. Here's a perfectly valid Go function that will make a C programmer's skin crawl:

```
func foo() *int {
    a := 1
    return &a
}
```

This is fine because the Go compiler will figure out that the variable `a` needs to be allocated on the heap. It will be garbage collected later and you don't have to care. (Well, ok, in some situations you might. But most of the time you don't.)

You can concoct all kinds of scenarios where the compiler will do things like this. It just wouldn't be the same without a garbage collector.

There are things you can do to help GC times, but to a certain extent you'll be nullifying the advantages of the language. I hesitate to recommend these practices, but are options:

- Free lists
- With the unsafe package you can even write your own allocator and manually free memory, but you'd need a function for every type you want to allocate. Or use reflection to pass in the type you want to allocate, return an empty interface, and use type assertions to get concrete values out.

The bottom line is, Go probably isn't a good choice for applications with hard real-time requirements. That said, I also don't think you'll see anything approaching a 10 second garbage collection. Consider what your requirements really are and if you have any doubts, do some measurements.

Try the latest Go code if you can. There are some garbage collector improvements and some compiler optimizations that cause fewer allocations. If your release time frame is shorter, though, you may be stuck with the current stable release for several months.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions - it's good to hear about new developments in go.  I expect that in go, I can help the gc along by doing things like allocating in large chunks rather allocating many small objects and by writing tighter code...

Comment: Yes, things like free lists can help. Edited my answer a little.

Comment: @EvanShaw, you can get away with reference counting GC, for the examples you've given, and you get deterministic run time. I think CPython have ref-counting GC, and it gets away with it, if the user keep away from cyclic data structures. Can't you do similar thing to Go?

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich, I think you could. I'm not sure how well the ref counting would interact with goroutines though.

Comment: @EvanShaw, Care to explain further? Why do you think ref counting won't work with goroutines? Are you worried about the price of thread-safe ref-counting? Is there inherent cyclic references involved with goroutines? CPython can do CSP as well, and it seems to work.

Comment: @ElazarLeibovich, I don't know enough about it, but yes, I'm worried about thread-safe ref-counting. I'm not aware of any inherent cyclic references in Go, but I haven't thought about it much.